# Sync data from SQL Server to MS Access on different environment

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to sync a specific SQL Server table, so that when there is a change in that table, the MS Access database on a different environment will be updated as well (same table schema in both SQL Server and MS Access).

The only way the two environments communicate with each other is through SFTP server.

My idea was:

1. whenever a change is made in the SQL Server table, it will generate an update/insert/delete string and write it to a file.
2. upload this file to the SFTP server.
3. In the MS Access environment, check if there is a file on the SFTP server; if there is a file, download and execute the update/insert/delete commands

Notes:

- Changes not made that often - let's say about 4-10 times a day
- SQL Server updates MS Access, not the other way around

Does my solution sounds good? is there a more efficient way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Open the sql port in your host machine. using odbc linked tables in MS Access

Comment: I can’t, as I mention in my question, the SQL Server and MS Access located in a different networks...